# SD card partitions not visible on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, dd, fdisk

I am trying to create a SD card with partitions for using the SD card to boot Linux on a ARM A9 processor. Now initially when the SD card was equipped with all partitions, I inserted it into the Ubuntu machine and was able to see 3 partitions (mmcblk0p1 - mmcblk0p3). I could also see these partitions through the Ubuntu file explorer.

Now for recreating a new SD card partition, I unmounted the SD card with the options provided by the file explorer of Ubuntu. Later I used the `sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0` command to create three new partitions, as follows:
`o` : to create a new partition table

Using the commands `n,p` to create 3 partitions in the SD card.

```
Partition 1 : 100M 
Type : W95/FAT32(b)

Partition 2 : 1G
Type : Linux(83)

Partition 3 : 1M
Type : Unknown(0x82)
```

Later on, I copied the pre-loader and bootloader image to partition 3 using `dd`.

The kernel device tree blob, zImage, u-boot was copied to partition 1.

The whole file system should be copied to Partition 2. I have a tar file with the `debian rootfs` that needs to be copied to the partition 2. After extraction of tar file, I have a complete `rootfs` filesystem.

So I have the 2 questions right now :

1. How do I copy the complete `rootfs` folder to the Partition 2. The command `dd`only works for the individual files.
2. How can I see the 3 partitions in the Ubuntu file explorer? Currently I can only see one partition with 105MB in the Ubuntu file explorer.

I have used `gnome-disk` utility and I can see the partitions in gnome. See gnome-disk utility screen-shot:

[image: screen-shot]

Output for `fdisk -l` command :

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3,7 GiB, 3980394496 bytes, 7774208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe7e58d0a

Device         Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1         2048  206847  204800  100M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p2       206848 2303999 2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3      2304000 2306047    2048    1M a2 unknown
```

Output for `lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   1   1,9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   1   1,9G  0 part /media/find/USB DISK
sda           8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0  15,7G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1        8:1    0 217,2G  0 part /
mmcblk0     179:0    0   3,7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0     1G  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p3 179:3    0     1M  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   100M  0 part /media/find/2625-2AC3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully set up your partition table, but only the first partition has a filesystem set up in it (this is why Ubuntu didn't automount the other two partitions). You can create an ext4 filesystem for your second partition with "sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p2". After this, Ubuntu should mount the second partition (you might have to restart, I don't know how smart the automount service is), and you can copy over your files with a "cp -r".